# Flutter - Is it possible to show a snackbar inside another Container than the one used to trigger .show?

Tags: flutter, dart, snackbar

Is it possible to have the snackbar appearing only in another widget?
I am trying something like that so that when we click on the button the snackbar would only be embedded inside the Container, not appearing outside of it but it is not working:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  BuildContext snackContext;
  return Stack(
    children: [
      Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        snackContext = context;
        return Container(height: 300, width: 300, child: Text('Test'));
      }),
      TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(snackContext).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(
              backgroundColor: Color(0x44000000),
              content: Text(
                'Test of snackbar',
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      )
    ],
  );
}
```

Please advise~

Answer (score 0):

Save the correct context in the `State`. This code works for me:

```dart
class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  BuildContext snackContext;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 300,
            width: 200,
            child: Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
              body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                snackContext = context;
                return Container(height: 300, width: 300, child: Text('Test'));
              }),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Scaffold.of(snackContext).showSnackBar(
                  SnackBar(
                    backgroundColor: Color(0x44000000),
                    content: Text(
                      'Test of snackbar',
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: Text('data'),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestPageState createState() => _TestPageState();
}
```